# How to enable ESM on Xenial?

Tags: 16.04, esm

Ubuntu Xenial enters ESM mode as it stated at the [official Ubuntu blog post](https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-esm-migration-path).

I'm trying to set up ESM to get ready for that but ubuntu-advantage tool says

```
# ubuntu-advantage enable-esm
Sorry, but Extended Security Maintenance is not supported on xenial
```

In my Ubuntu Advantage subscription I can see

```
If you’re using Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 LTS, you don’t need to attach machines.
```

What is the proper way to configure ESM on Xenial? How can I test that it's properly enabled and works in advance? Has it been enabled for Xenial yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Extended Security Maintenance for Ubuntu 16.04

First priority when retaining Ubuntu 16.04 is security. This means signing up for **Ubuntu Advantage (UA) client** and installing **ESM**.

Following is my experience installing ESM:

The Ubuntu discourse page for information on installing Ubuntu ESM is https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-advantage-client/21788. The page directed me to https://ubuntu.com/advantage where I completed the registration process and ended up with a **free token**.

Back on https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-advantage-client/21788 I continued with **Installing the UA client** by running a couple of commands as instructed. Next I proceeded to **Attach the UA client**. I ran the line I got when registering `sudo ua attach [TOKEN_ID]`, (Please use your own free token).

Running `sudo ua status` I confirmed that ESM was enabled.

I completed the upgrade by running `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`. The installer ran for quite a while.

I ran Software Updater and It installed quite a few security updates.
All Settings/Overview tells me **System Up-To-Date**.

Answer (score 0):

You are too early.

Canonical announced today that their Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) operating system series will enter Extended Security Maintenance (ESM) support beginning April 30th, 2021. It is not the 30 th. yet.

Try again on or after the 30th. https://ubuntu.com/security/esm

Comment: Today?   I recall posting awhile ago that ESM will be available April 30 - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/  (March 13, 2021 and I just re-post official announcements etc; the fridge can be a little behind as poster needs to have post reviewed etc)

Comment: I was quoting the web site.