# apt-get update fails due to NO_PUBKEY in FIPS mode

Tags: apt, updates

I encountered some common errors while running `apt-get update` - no public keys.

My Ubuntu is in fips mode, version `5.4.0-1092-fips`.

The errors I'm seeing while running `apt-get update` is

```
Err:5 https://esm.ubuntu.com/fips-updates/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY $MY_KEY1
Err:6 https://esm.ubuntu.com/cis/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY $MY_KEY2
```

I followed [apt-get update fails due to NO_PUBKEY 6AF7F09730B3F0A4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389758/apt-get-update-fails-due-to-no-pubkey-6af7f09730b3f0a4), and tried

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys $MY_KEY1
and
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys $MY_KEY1
```

The output is

```
gpg: out of core handler ignored in FIPS mode
gpg: key $MY_KEY1: public key "Ubuntu Federal Information Processing Standards Automatic Signing Key V1 <esm@canonical.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: out of core handler ignored in FIPS mode
gpg: out of core handler ignored in FIPS mode
```

I don't know if this command registered the key successfully. I can see the keys from `gpg --list-keys`. However, `apt-get update` still fails with the same error.

What can I do in this case? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Some people marked this dup to [How to enable ESM on Xenial?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334043/how-to-enable-esm-on-xenial) , but I don't see how that post answered my question to fix the no public key issue.

**Edit 2:**
Still doesn't work after I went pro mode and enabled ESM

```
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS       DESCRIPTION
anbox-cloud      yes       disabled     Scalable Android in the cloud
esm-apps         yes       enabled      Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       enabled      Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
fips-updates     yes       enabled      FIPS compliant crypto packages with stable security updates
livepatch        yes       enabled      Canonical Livepatch service
ros              yes       disabled     Security Updates for the Robot Operating System
usg              yes       enabled      Security compliance and audit tools

NOTICES
Operation in progress: pro attach
```

**Edit 3:** Please take a look at my post. I followed the old posts to import the keys but it still didn't work. A similar issue that I found is [GPG error, but could not update public key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456569/gpg-error-but-could-not-update-public-key) but that doesn't have an answer, either.

Comment: Not quite. I don't see anything in that post help me fix the no public key issue for `apt-get update`

Comment: The keys should have been added when you *enable* ESM.

Comment: @guiverc nope it still doesn't work after I enabled ESM

Comment: Maybe you could try to reinstall/reenable FIPS. Look [here](https://ubuntu.com/security/certifications/docs/fips-enablement) for more infos

Comment: Make sure your computer time is set correctly, because keys may expire. But I wouldn't be surprised if this has to do withe the  file permissions of the trust store /etc/apt/trusted.gpg ... It may also be that in fips mode you need  different update methods than apt. https://ubuntu.com/security/certifications/docs/fips-enablement

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Ubuntu you are running, you need the ESM GPG keys installed first before doing apt updates.

https://esm.ubuntu.com/fips-updates/ubuntu/dists/
Index of /fips-updates/ubuntu/dists/
../
bionic-updates/
focal-updates/
jammy-updates/
xenial-updates/

You will need to install the GPG key for your version of Ubuntu.  For my 22.4.04 LTS jammy jellyfish it would be:

https://esm.ubuntu.com/fips-updates/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/Release.gpg

The key can be installed with the following command
curl -fsSL https://esm.ubuntu.com/fips-updates/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/Release.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/esm.gpg

Once the GPG key is installed, apt-get update should work without complaint on keys